# Releasing of thread's lock when it sleeps

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, sleep

How can I release the lock of thread when it is sleeping?

When I call pthread_join(), it will run just fine, but I have to create more than one threads and I can't call pthread_join() because of their concurrency. How can I resolve this issue without calling join.

```
pthread_mutex_t mut1;
pthread_mutex_init(&mut1, NULL);

void* funA(void* arg){    
      while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mut1) != 0);
      sleep(10);
      // resources sharing
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
      pthread_t id[9];
      for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
          pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, &funA, NULL);
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Why can you not just release the mutex before the sleep and reacquire it after?

Comment: A thread should never sleep while holding a lock.

Comment: I can not release and then reacquire mutex. In my project, i am doing this  to check synchronization. so when thread sleeps, they are not using resources properly.

Comment: What does that mean,  "...to check synchronization?" If you are hoping to write an automated test that will fail if the code is not properly synchronized, then good luck with that! Testing for synchronization bugs is virtually impossible. Improperly synchronized code is never _guaranteed_ to behave badly. If the code passes in your test harness, that's no guarantee that it won't fail at a customer site.

Comment: Calling `pthread_join()` is mandatory -- you can't skip it and expect your program to work correctly.  Call `pthread_join` in a second for-loop in `main()`, after your first for-loop has completed.  That will give you both concurrency and a clean exit.

Comment: What is the purpose of that `while` loop? That will do horrible things to the CPU. I'm also somewhat confused -- do you want the lock released while the thread sleeps or not? Your question says yes but your comment says no!